El instalador de postgresql lanza error de accesso denegado
Al momento que quiero iniciar el instalador de postgresql en Windows ocurre un error de accesso en mi carpeta TEMP, ya intenté varias cosas entre cambiar el path de mi carpeta Temp, instalar por medio del source code pero no he podido.
Intenté ejecutarlo como administrador y descargué varias versiones del instalador.


¿estás ejecutando el instalador como administrador?

Sí, ya intenté ejecutarlo como administrador

De dónde sale la ruta "C:\Temp Nuevo/", realmente no parece válida.

La ruta "C:\Temp Nuevo/ "decidí cambiarla porque leí en internet que eso podría ayudar. Leí que cambiar el Path de la carpeta Temp podía servir. Puedo regresarlo al Path original pero sigue sin funcionar.

justo hoy he estado intentando instalar PostgreeSql, y me he encontrado con el mismo error en Windows 11, al igual que tú he instalado varias versiones y obtuve el mismo error, sin embargo buscando en otros foros he llegado a este link que al menos a mi me ha funcionado, hasta ahora no he tenido problemas, espero que te funcione al igual que a mi.

No he podido encontrar una solucion a este erro al instalar postgres, que debo de hacer no me deja instalar ninguna version 


Introducción

Buen día, yo tengo ese mismo problema y creo que sé la razón, por desgracia la solución es mas díficil de lo que parece.
El problema creo que es que el instalador crea una carpeta en /temp, pero no tiene permiso de modificarla directamente, y esto también pasa si vas en el Explorador de archivos a /temp y lo intentas hacer tú mismo.

Cosas que aprendí o intenté y pequeños avances:


El error viene de que ni el programa ni el usuario tiene permiso
para ejecutar el comando "icacls" con esos parámetros.
Una vez ejecutado el comando "icacls "C:\temp" /reset /T /C /Q" se elimina esa restricción tanto el programa como para tí.
Espero que ayude, sigo teniendo ese error, cualquier solución agracecería que me avisasen.

Solución
En mi caso la razón del problema es que estaba iniciando sesión en Windows con una cuenta de dominio en vez de una de local. Si inicias sesión con una cuenta de dominio esta no tendrá permisos para modificar la carpeta %temp%.

En mi caso se solucionó

habilitando el usuario "Administrador" que viene por defecto en windows.
le coloqué una contraseña
Luego le dí shift + segundo click al instalador
coloqué las credenciales del administrador que había habilitado anteriormente

y pude instalar sin problemas.
